# Can moderators see deleted posts in chat and enter closed rooms?

Tags: support, chat, moderation, deleted-comments

In chat.stackoverflow.com only the owner of the room has the right to see deleted post. But I don't know whether moderators have that right to see deleted post or not?

And do they have access to enter closed rooms (rooms only for authorized users)?

Comment: Yes. Moderators can see everything - including the future. If they see that you will be banned, they can make it happen. :)

Comment: @Mysticial lolz... i know that feature very well... :D

Comment: 10k users can see deleted conversations as well.

Comment: @TravisJ but this post says [Nobody else can see them. In particular, this is not related to reputation (unlike the ability to see deleted rooms).](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134920/229796).. what is TRUE ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ - Both. A deleted conversation in the context I was referring to was an entire room's transcript. In your link, balpha is talking about specific individual messages being deleted. The entire room's deleted transcript is available to 10k users. Only mods can see specific individual deleted messages from a transcript view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Moderators can see deleted posts, and summaries of posts that have been flagged *per user*; this is in order to be able to respond to things that have been escalated effectively.

It's difficult to arrive to a room, figure out what's going on and (more importantly) who might be behind a series of disruptions - so they have some tools to help with that. They aren't *great*, but one should assume that anything you type *as a contribution* - be it question, answer, comment, chat message - mods can see it regardless of state.

The exception to this is if a post has been disassociated from your chat account, but there's only a few people that can do this, and they work here. Mods could still see the post, just not who posted it.

tl;dr - Don't type things in chat you wouldn't want a mod (or anyone else) to see, do *not* expect any kind of privacy when using chat, unless a moderator (identified by a diamond next to their name) informs you that only moderators can access the room you're talking in.

Yes, moderators that have privileges in chat may enter any room. Chat is by default a very public thing, the only 'private' communication there can be initiated *by* moderators, and *only* for the purposes of moderation, which can be viewed (depending on chat SO / chat SE) all mods on the network, or the Stack Overflow moderators.

Point is, *nothing* in chat is private, *rare conversations* are confidential, and can only be marked as such by a mod.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. i have slightly updated my question as well. Can you please see that as well?

Comment: thanx for your answer

Comment: What happen when i tag u using "@" its not showing it here.. what will be the reason?

Comment: We're the only two commenting under this answer, is the reason. `@` replies are only needed when there's more than one user conversing - we're automatically notified without them.

Comment: but in SO i guess that's happening...

Comment: Huh? What's happening?

Comment: i got ur updated answer...